# line length in forest plot R

Tags: r, plot

I have  a data.frame

```
> s1g2
                      centre    Estimate          Var   n
factor(groupchange)2       1   0.6821912 1.486330e+00 217
factor(groupchange)21      2   0.3535025 1.622455e+00 165
factor(groupchange)22      3 -15.4053858 3.284365e+06 152
factor(groupchange)23      4  -0.2659903 1.837585e+00 137
factor(groupchange)24      5   0.4702335 2.198379e+00 201
factor(groupchange)25      6   1.1657077 9.546860e-01 159
>
```

I would like to plot it using the forest command of the `metafor` library

This is what I have tried

```
res <- rma(Estimate, Var, data=s1g2, method="ML")
sav <- blup(res)

par(family="mono", mar=c(5,4,1,2))
forest(res, refline=res$b, addcred=TRUE, xlim=c(-7,8),alim=c(-3,3), slab=1:6, psize=.8,
       ilab=paste0("(n = ", formatC(s1g2[["n"]], width=3, big.mark=","), ")"),
       ilab.xpos=-3.5, ilab.pos=2, rows=6:1+.15)

text(-7, 15, "Trial (total n)", pos=4)
text( 8, 15, "Log Odds Ratio [95% CI]", pos=2)
```

It works but the arrow for centre=3 is too long on the left. 
How can I reduce it?   The command `alim` seems to work only for the right side.

Also a solution using another library for the plot would be accepted. 
I would like something like : http://mcfromnz.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/forest_plot_2.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the estimates represent, but there is one centre with a value of -15.41 (and a huge variance) that seems way different than the rest. With axis limits of -3 to 3, the estimate would actually not be shown and the CI is so wide, it would cover the entire axis range.

At any rate, the various `forest` functions in the `metafor` package enforce plot/axis limits that encompass the actual data. That's why the plot/axis limits are extended to that -15.41 value.

In essence, it is these lines in `forest.rma` that you don't need:

```
if (xlim[1] > min(yi, na.rm = TRUE)) {
    xlim[1] <- min(yi, na.rm = TRUE)
}
if (xlim[2] < max(yi, na.rm = TRUE)) {
    xlim[2] <- max(yi, na.rm = TRUE)
}
if (alim[1] > min(yi, na.rm = TRUE)) {
    alim[1] <- min(yi, na.rm = TRUE)
}
if (alim[2] < max(yi, na.rm = TRUE)) {
    alim[2] <- max(yi, na.rm = TRUE)
```

So, one option would be to download the source package, comment out those lines, and then install the package from source.

Here is a bit of a hack solution:

```
res <- rma(Estimate, Var, data=s1g2, method="ML")
res$yi.f[3] <- NA
res$vi.f[3] <- NA

options(na.action="na.pass")
par(family="mono", mar=c(5,4,1,2))
forest(res, refline=res$b, addcred=TRUE, xlim=c(-7,8),alim=c(-3,3), slab=1:6, psize=.8,
       ilab=paste0("(n = ", formatC(s1g2[["n"]], width=3, big.mark=","), ")"),
       ilab.xpos=-3.5, ilab.pos=2, rows=6:1+.15)
text(-7, 15, "Trial (total n)", pos=4)
text( 8, 15, "Log Odds Ratio [95% CI]", pos=2)

library("shape")
Arrows(-3, 4.15, 3, 4.15, code=3, arr.type="triangle", )
rect(4, 3.5, 8, 4.5, col="white", border=NA)
text(4, 4.15, "-15.41 [ see note ]", pos=4)
```

You will have to twiddle with the arrow length/height to make it look just like the other ones (see `help(Arrows)`). And you will have to play around with the positioning of the text. I would not add the actual CI bounds (-3567.41 to 3536.60) as these are essentially meaningless. Instead, I would add a note to the plot explaining the issue.